How to check whether a BigQuery table is not populated and publish a failure message to the Slack channel?
I need to create a solution (using Terraform) that checks the BigQuery table is not empty on a daily basis, and if it's empty, it should publish an alert in alerts Slack channel. Problem to implement it is that scheduled query configuration has only 2 options:

publish a message to email
publish a message to the Pub/Sub topic
How can I implement it using scheduled query and maybe additional configuration ?

I'm using the following query to check if the table is not populated.
ASSERT NOT EXISTS(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ${var.project_id}.${local.dataset_name}.${local.table_name} where DATE(UPDATED_AT) < DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())) AS "Table has no records"

After some investigation of GCP documentation, I have found a solution. So I've found the following flow.
Scheduled queries on a daily basis check the BigQuery table using the above-mentioned query. In case the table is empty, a scheduled query publishes a message to GCP Pub/Sub. GCP Cloud Function written using Python listens to the Pub/Sub cloud event, and if there is a new message in Pub/Sub, it consumes a message and publishes it to the corresponding Slack channel.
What should be done:

Create a Pub/Sub topic using Terraform
Create a Scheduled query using Terraform
Create a Cloud Function using Python
Create a Deployment for Cloud Function using GitHub Actions

Pub/Sub topic using Terraform
resource "google_pubsub_topic" "topic-name" {           
 name    = "pubsub-topic-name"           
 project = var.project_id         
}

Сreate a Scheduled query using Terraform
resource "google_bigquery_data_transfer_config" "scheduled_query_name {                   
 depends_on = [module.bigquery_dataset]                                    
 display_name         = "Check if BigQuery table is not populated"                   
 location             = var.euw4_region                   
 service_account_name = module.service_account_name.email                   
 data_source_id       = "scheduled_query"                   
 schedule             = "every day 08:00"                   
 params = {                     
 query = "ASSERT NOT EXISTS(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `${var.project_id}.${local.dataset_name}.${local.table_name}` where DATE(UPDATED_AT) < DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())) AS \"Table has no records\""                 }
 notification_pubsub_topic = "projects/${var.project_id}/topics/topic_name"                   project                   = var.project_id                 
 }

Create a Cloud Function using Python
import base64     
import functions_framework     
import os from slack_sdk 
import WebClient          

slack_token = os.environ["SLACK_TOKEN"]     
client = WebClient(token=slack_token)          

@functions_framework.cloud_event     
def process_pubsub_message(event):         
    data: Dict = event.data                
    slack_text = base64.b64decode(data["message"]["data"]).decode('utf-8')   
    slack_channel_id="your_channel_id"         
    client.chat_postMessage(channel=slack_channel_id, text=slack_text)

Create a Deployment for Cloud Function using GitHub Actions
gcloud functions deploy "${{ env.CLOUD_FUNCTION_NAME }}" \         
--region "${{ env.REGION }}" \         
--entry-point process_pubsub_message \         
--gen2 \         
--runtime python312 \         
--timeout 60s \         
--project ${{ vars.GCP_PROJECT_ID }} \         
--service-account your-service-account-sa@${{ vars.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \         
--build-service-account projects/${{ vars.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/serviceAccounts/your-service-account-sa@${{ vars.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \         
--run-service-account your-service-account-sa@${{ vars.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \         
--source ./CloudFunction \         
--trigger-topic topic-name \
--set-env-vars SLACK_TOKEN=${{ secrets.SLACK_TOKEN }}

Also not to forget to define SLACK_TOKEN in secrets
